# Graphics library used by Windows Vista Freecell and Solitaire

Tags: graphics, windows-vista, 2d

What graphics library is used to create the graphics in the Solitaire and Freecell games included with Windows Vista (e.g. XNA, GDI, WPF)?  A good answer would include the name of the library and evidence.

I looked at solitaire.exe with [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and it shows many calls to gdi32.dll and gdiplus.dll, but also a call to Direct3DCreate9 in d3d9.dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses Direct3D 9, via the C++ COM interfaces.  You have all the evidence you need in the call to Direct3DCreate9; that is all that the game requires to get an IDirect3D9* interface, at which point it can create a device interface etc.